# How to boycott making html element when setting innerHTML

Tags: html

My problem is when setting innerHTML of an element, I do something along the lines of `innerHTML = "<span class="handle"><sunstorm></span>"`. I want to wrap the string `<sunstorm>` in a span element but instead its recognising `<sunstorm>` as an HTML element. Is it possible to disable this using a character like `\<` or is there a better alternative to wrapping the string in a span?

Thank you

Comment: Please explain better because Ididn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: How can I create a span element with content `<sunstorm>` without html looking at `<sunstorm>` as an element because of the arrows?

Comment: You can use `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`. See [this chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) of HTML entities.

```js
document.querySelector('.handle').innerHTML = '<span class="handle">&lt;sunstorm&gt;</span>';
```

```html
<span class="handle"></span>
```

Comment: This works, however, now the `span` element is not working or showing up through inspect, how can I solve this?

Comment: @Sean I can see it in this example. Make sure you're using `innerHTML` and not `outerHTML`. https://imgur.com/a/vyiGcOW

Comment: This is how I am setting the innerHTML in my code:
```messageLine.innerHTML += tFormat + ' <span class="handle">&lt;sunstorm&gt;</span>';

  messageLine.textContent += `${str} \r\n`;
```
It isn't producing the span element unfortunately

Comment: @Sean I would ask if `messageLine` is a `TextNode`, because then you might have an issue - but if that were the case, you wouldn't have had this problem in the first place? How can only *one* of these tags be parsing as an element?

Comment: @Sean can you do `console.log(document.querySelector('.handle'))` and see what you get? If it's `undefined` can you post `console.log(messageLine)`?

Comment: it is a textnode, would it be better if I moved all the content into a span element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215881/discussion-between-sean-and-christian).

Comment: @Sean You can do either. Let me explain the situation. If you set an *element's* `innerHTML` property, it's going to parse what you put inside, so you need to replace any `<` or `>` XML chars with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. If it's a `TextNode`, it's parsing text, it doesn't have children, and you *don't* need to sanitize the input. Chrome's inspector displays text nodes as preformatted text inside double quotes, like `"text"`.